# Laravel eloquent combine max() and where() or having()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm looking for an eloquent statement that will give me the max(timestamp) for each room_id, given that all timestamp values are older than 15 days for that room_id.  (essentially any room that hasn't been cleaned in the past 15 days...)

**maintenancelog**

```
+----+-------------------+---------+---------------------+
| id | maintenance_value | room_id |      timestamp      |
+----+-------------------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | Cleaned           |       1 | 2015-09-06 00:54:59 |
|  2 | Cleaned           |       1 | 2015-09-07 01:55:59 |
|  3 | Cleaned           |       2 | 2015-09-06 02:56:59 |
|  4 | Cleaned           |       2 | 2015-09-16 03:57:59 |
|  5 | Cleaned           |       3 | 2015-09-06 04:58:59 |
|  6 | Cleaned           |       3 | 2015-09-07 05:59:59 |
+----+-------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

I suck with MySQL, but this would be equivalent of an Oracle statement of...

```
select room_id,max(timestamp) from maintenancelog
group by room_id
having max(timestamp) < sysdate - 15;
```

The eloquent statement should return essentially the following.

```
1, 2015-09-07 01:55:59
3, 2015-09-07 05:59:59
```

I've tried...

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
$checkdate = $dt->subDays(15);
return $this->groupBy('room_id')->max('timestamp')->having('timestamp','<',$checkdate);
```

but get

```
Call to a member function having() on string
```

trying...

```
return $this->groupBy('room_id')->havingRaw("max(timestamp)<sysdate()-15");
```

just returns any rows where timestamp is older than 15, ignoring the other max values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

max() like count() is a final function in eloquent in place of get(). What you really want is max() in the select as a raw statement.

```
return $this->select(DB::raw('room_id, max(`timestamp`) as `timestamp`'))
    ->groupBy('room_id')
    ->having('timestamp','<',$checkdate)
    ->get();
```